# How to host flask app on GCP using gunicorn?

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn, flask-restful, apache-superset

I am trying to host my superset app on GCP using Gunicorn on a development mode. Here's my configuration:

App Installation instructions: https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html
App configuration instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

Note that I am turning on port listening using:

```
sudo ufw allow 8088
```

To run the app:

```
superset run -p 8088 -h 0.0.0.0
```

The link which I want to access: http://gcp_external_ip:8088

But it's not responding.

Note that I have setup for all HTTP and https traffic:
[image]

Here's my command shell:
[image]

Kindly let me know where am I going wrong? I am not able to access the server from my other system:
[image]

External ping is also happening:
[image]

Comment: try debug with localhost:8088,  and make sure upstream port 5000 is proxy to 8088

Comment: Didn't get you? you mean to add a flag --debug localhost:8088?

Comment: try to ping: external_ip:port to see whether it is reachable from your machine firstly

Comment: Yes ping is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change port on which your app is exposed to the Internet - if you're OK with 8088 then use it.

Just make sure that you [create a GCP firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) to let the traffic in. By default `HTTP server` and `HTTPS server` open ports 80 and 443 respectively. Port 8088 is blocked by default.

Example firewall rule to open up port 8080 for an instance with "tag1" tag from all IP's:

`gcloud compute --project=myproject firewall-rules create port8088 --direction=INGRESS --priority=1000 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:8088 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags=tag1`

Also - assign "tag1" tag to the VM you want to "unblock".

Comment: That's exactly what I did thanks a ton, this will help others who may run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The allow HTTP opens the 80 port in the GCP VPC firewall. Change the serving port of your flask application to port 80

Comment: Just 80 or 8080?

Comment: According to this https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance I believe that only 80

Comment: Hmm thanks for sharing, but this didn't work as well :-/

Comment: Make sure that you are accessing via HTTP not HTTPS, if not hardcoded on the url browsers will automatically understand that you want HTTPS

Comment: Yes, yes I am making http request only every single time.

Comment: But running with port 80 gives the following error

`File "/home/bmabir/anaconda3/envs/360_image_clf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1030, in run_simple
    s.bind(server_address)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`

Is it wise to run the app with sudo?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with setting up the firewall ports and allowed them to access in HTTP and https in firewall settings by adding the ports. Thanks to @Guillem for helping out! If anyone faces this issue do add comments and I will reach to you asap.